# For a hash of objects in ruby, hash.keys.index(obj) works but hash.has_key?(obj) does not. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

Here's my Rails class

```
class SkinnyEmployee
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :uid, :name

  validates :uid, :presence => true

  def initialize(id, name)
    @uid = id
    @name = name
  end

  def ==(other)
    puts "Calling =="
    raise ArgumentError.new("other is nil or bad in "+self.to_s) if other.nil? or !other.instance_of?(SkinnyEmployee)
    return (self.class == other.class && self.uid == other.uid)
  end

  alias :eql? :==

end
```

I have a hash of SkinnyEmployee objects. E.g.,

```
skinny_hash = {SkinnyEmployee.new("123", "xyz") => 1, SkinnyEmployee.new("456", "abc") => 2}
```

I have another SkinnyEmployee object that I want to look up. E.g.,

```
entry = SkinnyEmployee.new("456", "abc")
```

When I do

```
skinny_hash.keys.index(entry)
```

I get 1, as expected. But when I do

```
skinny_hash.has_key?(entry)
```

I get false.

Why is that? Doesn't has_key? also use == or eql? to find whether a key exists in a hash?

Thanks much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this drove me nuts.  What you're doing looked absolutely correct to me, and, as you already know, doesn't work.

I can take you part of the way to a solution:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-hash

quoting:

> Generates a Fixnum hash value for this object. This function must have the property that a.eql?(b) implies a.hash == b.hash.
>
> The hash value is used along with eql? by the Hash class to determine if two objects reference the same hash key. Any hash value that exceeds the capacity of a Fixnum will be truncated before being used.

I added:

```
def hash
    1
end
```

to your SkinnyEmployee Class, and has_key? started returning true.  Obviously that's not a solution, but I'm thinking it at least puts you on the path to one.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was the only one being driven nuts by this. :)
I added the following method:
    def hash
      return @uid.hash
    end
And it works now. This was educational.

Answer (score 0):

You have overwritten the `eql?` method used by `Array#index` but not the `hash` method used by `Hash#has_key?`.

From Ruby [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-hash) for `Object#hash`

```
Generates a Fixnum hash value for this object. This function must have the property that a.eql?(b) implies a.hash == b.hash.
```

The `Object#hash` and `Object#eql?` methods return equal if and only if the objects occupy the same space in memory. Some classes like `Array` overwrite both methods to return true if the compared array's have same elements.

For your case you can define the `hash` method like:

```
  def hash
      "#{self.class}_#{self.uid}".hash
  end
```

This would satisfy the docs criteria for `hash` method given above.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I can't put a check mark against your answer too. :(

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because the object you are using as a key and they one you are using to search the key are different.

Every time you call SkinnyEmployee.new it will create a new, different, object. For example

```
employee_1 = SkinnyEmployee.new("123", "xyz")
employee_2 = SkinnyEmployee.new("123", "xyz")

employee_1 == employee_1 #=> true
employee_2 == employee_2 #=> true
employee_2 == employee_1 #=> false
```

If you call `object_id` on both `employee_1` and `employee_2` you will notice that it gives you different id's.

Using has_key? will check for the exact same object, and that won't be the case if you use `SkinnyEmployee.new("456", "abc")`.

You would need a way to retrieve the exact same object, store it in a variable or in the DB, you are using as a key and use it as an attribute for has_key? for it to work.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood my code. Since I have redefined ==, I do get true for
employee_2 == employee_1.

In any case, the other two answers helped solve the problem.